# PHP Toggle session variable

Tags: php

How do I create a PHP toggle? Every time I call this function I always get the same result. I think the problem is in initializing the variable at the very beginning but you can't have a non initialized session variable...

```
$_SESSION['trigger'] = 0;

function trig()
{
    if($_SESSION['trigger'] == 1)
        $_SESSION['trigger'] = 0;
    else if($_SESSION['trigger'] == 0)
        $_SESSION['trigger'] = 1;
    else
        $_SESSION['trigger'] = 'N/A';
                //echo the result of $_SESSION['trigger'] outside of the function.

}
```

Comment: `Every time I call this function I always get the same result.`  Which is _what_?  What do you get and what do you expect to happen and why is it not what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the initialisation conditionally:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['trigger'])) {
    $_SESSION['trigger'] = 0;
}
```

Or detect its existence inside the `trig()` function:

```
function trig()
{
    $old = isset($_SESSION['trigger']) ? (int)$_SESSION['trigger'] : 0;

    $_SESSION['trigger'] = 1 - $old;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the variable at the beginning of the script you overwrite any previous value and will always get the same result from `trig()`.

Instead, check for the existence of the 'trigger' key first; if it is set, run the check. If it is not set, initialize it. Something like this should help:

```
if (array_key_exists('trigger', $_SESSION)) {
    trig();
}
else {
    $_SESSION['trigger'] = 0;
}
```

Also, I assume that you have more script than you posted here, but if not, be sure to call `session_start()` before trying to access the $_SESSION superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
...
$trigger = (isset($_SESSION['trigger'])) ? $_SESSION['trigger'] : 0;
...
function trig($trigger) 
{
     switch($trigger){
         case 1:
             $trigger = 0;
             break;
         case 0:
             $trigger = 1:
             break;
         default:
             $trigger = 'N/A';
             break;
     }
     $_SESSION['trigger'] = $trigger;
     return true;
}
...
trig($trigger);
```